# Connection attempt failed with "ETIMEDOUT - Connection attempt > timed out

Tags: ftp, vsftpd

I have installed vsftp. Sometime my ftp is working but sometimes not. I am getting error

> Status: Connection attempt failed with "ETIMEDOUT - Connection attempt
> timed out".

I have talked to godaddy then they said i have to enable port 2224. do i need to do this? Also why should enable this?